# What happened to the lawsuit over Django Unchained?

Tags: django-unchained, legal

There seems to have been a lot of talk about script writers suing Quentin Tarantino over the movie idea of Django Unchained. Does anybody know what happened to that lawsuit? Was it settled or did the idea disappear into thin air?

Comment: Was just filed last December.  Won't hear about again until it settles or goes to trial.

Comment: @dbugger Well, that already seems like the start of an answer.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, since that's all there is, that's all I got. ;)

Comment: @dbugger I think that, at least in the US, if you file something it goes public right? Is there a link to the lawsuit itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The case is still going on.

The latest order was on July 7, 2016. The order granted "Consent Motion for Extension of Time to Answer" by the defendants (Columbia Pictures Industries, Inc.)

Here is the summary of that order:

> MINUTE ORDER: Granting25 Consent Motion for Extension of Time to
>   Answer. Defendant Columbia Pictures Industries, Inc. must answer or
>   otherwise respond to the Complaint within twenty days of the filing
>   date of the Court's ruling on The Weinstein Companys Motion to
>   Dismiss10 . Signed by Judge Tanya S. Chutkan on 7/7/16. (DJS)

Following is the link to the case:

[Case # 1:15-cv-02250](https://www.pacermonitor.com/public/case/10213341/COLVIN_et_al_v_TARANTINO_et_al), COLVIN et al v. TARANTINO et al, District Of Columbia District Court

To view the timelined summary of the case you *might* need to register on the website. To view the full text of the orders you need to pay.

For quick reading I have taken the screenshot of complete webpage and uploaded it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr0dI.jpg). Zoom in to read.

Comment: I am going to mark this as answered, anybody who is interested in the outcome can follow the link I presume (I didn't want to ask a question without a direct answer, but there it is, outcome yet unclear). Thanks mr Pale.

Comment: Yes that page on that link will give all the updates about that case. :)